# How to play with two afterActions in OwlCarousel

Tags: javascript, html, function, html5-video, owl-carousel

I have a problem with afterAction functions on my owl carousel.
The problem is that afterAction:syncPosition doesn't work when the second after Action "function(current)" is in the code. If I delete it, syncPosition works.

Currently I can't make a fiddle but maybe some of you can see a misspelled or something below.

UPDATE// ENTIRE CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    loop: false,
    navigation: true,
    pagination: true,
    paginationSpeed: 1000,
    singleItem: true,
    transitionStyle: "mask",
    autoHeight: true,
    autoPlay: 10000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
    navigationText : false,
    afterAction: syncPosition,
    afterAction: function(current) { 
        current.find('video').get(0).play();
    }
  });

  function syncPosition(el) {
    var current = this.currentItem;
    // code for smooth transition
    this.owl.owlItems.removeClass('turn-on');
    var t = this;

    $(this.owl.owlItems[this.owl.currentItem]).addClass('turn-on');
  }

});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 80) {
    $('.owl-pagination').addClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $('.owl-pagination').removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed

```
afterAction: function(current) { 
current.find('video').get(0).play();
}
```

to

```
afterInit: function(){
$("#sequence-1").find('video').get(0).play();
```

and both `syncPosition` and `.find('video').get(0).play();`
 are working.